# Unable to submit attachments from Power Apps form to SharePoint list, for users other than Owner

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I have a Power Apps application, containing a form, which submits to a SharePoint list.

The form has an attachments field, and the list has an attachments column.

When I run the application with the user which is the Owner of the app, everything works fine.

However, for other users, the attachment field will not be saved into the attachments column in the list.
(all other fields are saved OK; the only problem is with the attachment field)

It is precisely the situation described here: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Attachment-missing-in-SharePoint-list-after-submitting-form-from/td-p/2112481

However, the solution posted there is not acceptable for me: giving Edit rights to all users of the application implies giving them edit rights to documents in libraries, along with the right to edit items in lists.

Is there any other solution to this problem?

Comment: What permissions you granted for users on the list?

Comment: within the List Permissions category, only Add Items and View items;    from Site Permissions category: Browse Directories, Use Self-Service Site Creation , View Pages, Browse User Information ,  Use Remote Interfaces ,  Use Client Integration Features, Open,   Edit Personal User Information

Comment: I am not bound to this specific set of permissions; however, I would like user rights to be as limited as possible. And the edit items right - which is described as "Edit items in lists, edit documents in document libraries, and customize Web Part Pages in document libraries. " - is totally unnacceptable

Comment: If you have set permissions at the list level and when you grant "Edit items" permissions to users, they will be able to edit the items in that particular list only and not for other lists/libraries on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading attachments to SharePoint list items is considered as the "update/edit" operation in SharePoint.

Hence you will need permissions to update/edit list items.

Here are two options you can try:

1. Grant **Contribute** access on the SharePoint list to application users:

   Users should be able to add attachments to SharePoint list items using this permissions. Also, they will not have permissions to manage SharePoint list/library settings.
2. Upload attachments using flow and Owner user account:

   - Create a Power automate flow which will be triggered from Power Apps
   - Pass Attachments and list item ID from Power App to Power automate flow
   - Add attachments to list item using flow actions like: 
     [Add attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#add-attachment)
   - Change run-only permissions of the Power automate flow to always use the connection provided by flow owner who will have full control permissions on the list

Check: [Manage owners and users in your Microsoft list flows with Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/guidance/manage-list-flows)

Comment: Thank you for this fast reply. I will test this in detail and I will come with feedback.

Comment: Sure, let me know if any further help needed related to my answer.